# Django 1.11 built-in and custom widget template locations

Tags: django, templates, widget

I am trying to write a custom widget the "new way" with Django 1.11's new form/widget rendering functionality, and am very confused due to the lack of examples and well, lacking documentation:

From the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/renderers/#overriding-built-in-widget-templates):

> Each widget has a template_name attribute with a value such as
>   input.html. Built-in widget templates are stored in the
>   django/forms/widgets path. You can provide a custom template for
>   input.html by defining django/forms/widgets/input.html, for example.

I am unclear on the location it is referring to.  Does this mean in my `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/` directory, I'm supposed to create a new directory called `widgets/` and put my templates there?  Because that makes no sense.  Or am I supposed to create the django/forms/widgets/ directory under my project directory and put my new templates there?

Comment: @Alasdair django docs are horrible. They keep writing about tons of irrelevant things, like code snippets which doesn't even belong to any filename.. so i have no idea where to use those snippets. Especially with widgets, if you decide to do fully custom widget with template, have fun to find that info in docs.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add, remove or alter files in your Django installation directory `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django`.

To override `django/forms/widgets/input.html`, you would create a file `django/forms/widgets/input.html` in one of your template directories. Your template directories depend on your [`TEMPLATES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/templates/#configuration) setting.

Comment: But what does it mean by "Built-in widget templates are stored in the django/forms/widgets path."?  There is no such directory containing any files, only a module.

Comment: The default templates are in [`django/forms/templates`](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets).

Comment: Thank you, I have now discovered that what I'm looking for is in `venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/templates/django/forms/widgets`.  The docs didn't make that clear.